# No funciona Evento onClick jQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick

Tengo el evento **click** generado con jQuery, que esta siendo definido dentro de un `ready`, por algún motivo dentro del `ready` no funciona, pero fuera, si.

Código:

```
$(function(){
    $('#id').on("click", function(){ ..algo.. } ); // No funciona

    var aux = document.getElementById("id");
    console.log(aux); // es Null aun estando en el documento
});

// $('#id').on("click", function(){ ..algo.. } );  Si funciona
```

Version de Jquery: 2.2.3

Comment: ¿Nos podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que tendría que hacer tu programa? Si pudieras incluir un ejemplo reproducible sería perfecto.

Comment: Has intentado `$("body").on("click","#id",function(){---algo---})`

Comment: A ver, tienes que cerrar el bloque de `function` así: `});`, ya que el único cierre que tienes ahora sería el del `on.click`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código funciona bien, como podrás ver en la prueba de más abajo.

Aunque por lo general, los valores se usan dentro del ámbito de la función que genera un evento en específico, tal como el click de un botón. Son muy raros los casos en que se necesite usar los datos de una forma general dentro del DOM. También ten en cuenta que al no indicar lo que quieres del elemento, lo que obtienes es el elemento en sí. Generalmente lo que se busca de un elemento del tipo botón o del tipo `input` es su `id`, o el `value`, o el `text` que hay escrito en él.

En cuanto a `function`, estás aplicando la manera correcta, ya que `document.ready` ha sido declarado obsoleto a partir de jQuery 3.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#btnTest').on("click", function() {
    alert("Estamos en el ámbito del click, generalmente los valores se usan aquí");
  });
  var inputTest = document.getElementById("ibxTest").value;
  var buttonTest = document.getElementById("btnTest");
  console.log(inputTest);
  console.log(buttonTest);
  console.log(buttonTest.id);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ibxTest" value="Test" />
<button id="btnTest">Click para probar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, sería bueno saber en que parte de su documento javascript esta colocando el código, o bien si es en la misma vista, saber si lo colocó en la acción del documento $(document).ready(), sin embargo, lo que hago yo en ocasiones cuando quiero agregar un listener a un boton, link, label, etc, es solamente colocar lo que está dentro de su función. Es decir:

```
 <script>
       $('#id').on("click", function(){ ..algo.. } );
 </script>
```

Note que no está dentro de un función anónima, si no que dentro de los tags de script.

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/81578)

Comment: Nno entiendo como no proporciona una respuesta, si estoy señalando que el error puede estar al colocar el listener dentro de una función anónima y que prueba dejando hacer eso. Los comentarios del principio son para contextualizar mi respuesta. De todos modos seré más específico en una próxima oportunidad para no crear confusión en mi respuesta.

Comment: Tu lo has dicho. "puede estar". Además tanto en comentarios como en su respuesta @acedano especifica que parece ser un simple problema tipográfico. De todas maneras,mi revisión es solo una opinión, es posible que esté equivocado y por ello es necesario que mas usuarios coincidieran conmigo para que la respuesta fuese eliminada,cosa que no ha sucedido por el momento :)

Comment: Tomo tu comentario como una crítica constructiva, no como una crítica negativa. Seré mas certero para la próxima ocasión. Saludos!.

Comment: Por supuesto! Todos estamos aqui para aprender. En ningun caso mi intencion era negativa. Un saludo y a seguir aportando!

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

asi me funciona

Comment: puedes agregar una explicacion

Comment: `document.ready` es obsoleto desde jQuery 3. El OP debería conservar el código tal y como lo tiene (usando `function`) y sencillamente cerrar ese bloque. El código no le funciona porque falta un cierre: `});` Eso es todo, no hay que cambiar a un código obsoleto.